# Converting text to image is returning a small white box - php

Tags: php, php-gd

I'm working on a project where I have to convert some instructions text to images and send them by email.

For testing purpose, I'm trying a simple code to output a converted text as an image on the browser, but it's always returning a small white box like this:
[image]

I have GD installed on my server.
Here's my code:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/png");

function drawImage()
{
    $width = 0;
    $height = 0;
    $offset_x = 0;
    $offset_y = 0;
    $bounds = array();
    $image = "";

    $msg = "Some Sample Text....";
    $font = "ARIAL.TTF";
    $size = 24; // default font size.
    $rot = 0; // rotation in degrees.
    $pad = 0; // padding.
    $transparent = 1; // transparency set to on.
    $red = 0; // black text...
    $grn = 0;
    $blu = 0;
    $bg_red = 255; // on white background.
    $bg_grn = 255;
    $bg_blu = 255;

    // get the font height.
    $bounds = ImageTTFBBox($size, $rot, $font, "W");
    if ($rot < 0) 
    {
        $font_height = abs($bounds[7]-$bounds[1]);      
    } 
    else if ($rot > 0) 
    {
    $font_height = abs($bounds[1]-$bounds[7]);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $font_height = abs($bounds[7]-$bounds[1]);
    }
    // determine bounding box.
    $bounds = ImageTTFBBox($size, $rot, $font, $msg);
    if ($rot < 0) 
    {
        $width = abs($bounds[4]-$bounds[0]);
        $height = abs($bounds[3]-$bounds[7]);
        $offset_y = $font_height;
        $offset_x = 0;
    } 
    else if ($rot > 0) 
    {
        $width = abs($bounds[2]-$bounds[6]);
        $height = abs($bounds[1]-$bounds[5]);
        $offset_y = abs($bounds[7]-$bounds[5])+$font_height;
        $offset_x = abs($bounds[0]-$bounds[6]);
    } 
    else
    {
        $width = abs($bounds[4]-$bounds[6]);
        $height = abs($bounds[7]-$bounds[1]);
        $offset_y = $font_height;;
        $offset_x = 0;
    }

    $image = imagecreate($width+($pad*2)+1,$height+($pad*2)+1);
    $background = ImageColorAllocate($image, $bg_red, $bg_grn, $bg_blu);
    $foreground = ImageColorAllocate($image, $red, $grn, $blu);

    if ($transparent) ImageColorTransparent($image, $background);
    ImageInterlace($image, false);

    // render the image
    ImageTTFText($image, $size, $rot, $offset_x+$pad, $offset_y+$pad, $foreground, $font, $msg);

    // output PNG object.
    imagePNG($image);
}
drawImage(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this as simple as changing:

```
$image = imagereate
```

to

```
$image = imagecreate
```

Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: Thanks for help! Actually it's correct in the original code, and I corrected my post, sorry for that.